# Is there any way to continue the Nutch Crawl task which has been killed unexpected?

Tags: java, lucene, web-crawler, nutch

I have a Nutch crawl task which has been running a whole day long until i killed the process by a mistake.

I don't want to re-crawl the seeds (cost to much time), so i wonder whether there is a way or some Nutch Crawler parameters there, can make the crawler ignore those urls which has already been crawled.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you started crawling, there might be some segments created in the output directory. Use [bin/nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_crawl) command and point `-dir` option to the output directory of previous run. For `urlDir` argument, create a dummy one with a single url (just for getting away from error if the urldir doesnt have any url in it.)